# C: what should I use for trace/diagnostic messages in a library?

Tags: diagnostics

In .NET I would use System.Diagnostics.Trace...

What would I use in C or C++ ?

right now I have a macro defined:

diagnostics ON:

```
#define DIAG(A) { printf(A); }
```

debugging off:

```
#define DIAG(A) { if(FALSE) {}}
```

Is there a standard way?

Comment: Note that `printf(A)` is not safe, you should have used `printf("%s", A);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your environment. In Windows, I'd just use [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362(VS.85).aspx). There's [more complicated and configurable ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms793193.aspx), but I've never needed it myself.

Not sure if there's a standard on *nix, though. The relatively few times I've written *nix C code, I use a `DEBUG` envvar and `printf`.

Comment: On unix, you just have to use stderr. Use `cerr << A` instead of `printf(A)`. As a bonus, this is type safe.